eslint not recognize conditional exports (aka package exports)
I have a library that offers conditional exports:
node_modules/myLib/package.json:
{
...
  "exports": {
   "ComponentA": "../dist/ConponentA.js",
   "ComponentB": "../dist/ConponentB.js"
  }
}

myProject/package.json:
{
...
  "dependencies": {
    "myLib": "1.2.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.48.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2"
  }
}

My code works and looks like this:
..src/components/MyComponent.js

import {ComponentA, useA} from 'myLib/ComponentA'

...some react code...

The code works, the test works(with latest jest), but the linting (eslint) returns:
..src/components/MyComponent.js
  7:28  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'myLib/ComponentA'  import/no-unresolved

I did a dirt fix and set this rule to just warn, but this is not a solution.
¿How can I set eslint to recognize conditional exports?

Are you wanting to lint the source or the output of this module? If you are running lint on the output, you'll need to make sure the output is built via Webpack to dist.

I just want to not get this false error of import unresolved, webpack already processes the exports>import, but for some reason eslint fails to, also I just found this open ticket https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1810
